# BSON classes and updates in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, bson, upsert

I have a mongo collection and I've defined all the elements as BSON classes.
eg.

```
_id: 12345 
Person
-> Name
     surname: smith
     forename: john 
-> Address
     number: 1
     street: the street
```

Using this reading the data is simple and it is output nicely in a class so any consumers no nothing about mongo.

Now for updates, I'd just like to take in a customer key, eg _id and update the Address, but passing in an Address Class.

so update(_id, Address.class)

```
   updateAccount(String personId, Account account) {
    
       // set up connection to mongo etc...

       // Update record
       Document updDocQuery = new Document("_id", personId);
       Bson update = new Document("$set", address);
       UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)

       mongoCollection.updateOne(updDocQuery, update, updateOptions);
   }
```

Is this possible?  I've played around, but I can't seem to find a way of ensuring mongo updates the document in the collection at the correct level, i.e. under "Person" rather at the top level.  I'm sure I'm just missing something, unless this is a limitation and I need to specify the hierarchy somehow.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've answered my own question...but I stand to be corrected.

I've found out I can pass in a document location using Updates.set;

```
mongoCollection.updateOne(documentId, Updates.set("Person.Address", address));
```